Spam audits in LQA review queue show grayed
Many of the audits in the Low Quality Answers review queue are obvious spam links.  As a rule, the corresponding answers are deleted as spam, which you can see if you click through to the actual answer (maybe with the intent of flagging it).
As of a somewhat recent UI update (I don't remember when exactly, but sometime in March 2024) these (deleted) answers show up as gray (dimmed) in the review queue, which makes it much more obvious that there's something unusual about them.
An example:


That's not quite it.  This seems independent of what I did on the previous review task, and AFAICT the UI operates normally (at least, "Delete", "Submit" works).
